# Creating VM theme in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay-theme, liferay-7, liferay-velocity

I want to create VM theme in liferay 7. I made the changes in package.json and changed the templateLanguage to vm. Next I changed liferay-look-and-feel.xml and changed  tag value to cm and did gulp build. The vm files are created, but when i Deploy it to the server, I get this warning:

```
09:53:24,368 WARN  [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: a046c07b-9d60-0017-134e-c4d1864b896c][ThemeHotDeployListener:129] Support of Velocity is deprecated. Update theme testTheme to use FreeMarker for forward compatibility.
```

Also in the browser, the control panel and header tabs are not displayed and instead a warning is displayed as below:

```
 An app that can VIEW com.liferay.admin.kernel.util.PortalProductNavigationControlMenuApplicationType$ProductNavigationControlMenu belongs here. Please contact the portal administrator or install such an app from the Liferay Marketplace.
```

Below is the link of how the warning on browser is displayed: [Image of Warning Message](https://www.dropbox.com/s/slfddtkjoykemxm/Screenshot%20from%202017-07-04%2015-36-55.png?dl=0)

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem when i migrated the application from 6.2 to 7. Liferay 7 supports freemarker template language. When I used Velocity i used to get blank page and page not used to get displayed. I advice you to use freemarker.